# Give className to the matched element in forEach loop with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach

Guys i have a random word in my example and i am spliting that random word's letters to spans.

Then i check if there is specific letter in that word and use `forEach` loop to achieve this.
This is my function;

```
 getLetter:function(e){
   var val = e.currentTarget.textContent;
    this.state.letters.forEach(function(letter) {
     if (letter === val) {
     alert("There is 'r' letter in the word.")
     e.target.className = 'clicked';
     letter.className='foundedLetter';
    }
});
```

**I can give class `e.target` but can't give class the matched `letter` in forEach loop.**

How can i make it?

Thanks in advance.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4vwarggo/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your for-loop definition into a for of loop,
to make it more clear for the eye.

```
    getLetter(e)
    {
        var val = e.currentTarget.textContent;

        for (let letter of this.state.letters) {
            if (letter === val) 
            {
                e.target.className = 'clicked';
                letter.className = 'foundedLetter'
            }
        }
    }
```

This piece of code should work, unless if the letter variable you wanna give a className to is NOT a string character.

Make sure you rendered the spans as well. you could also look at this.refs and at a reference at your span. with this you can get the DOMElement and set a className to it. I will show you how to use refs to get DOMelements:

```
 var MyCom = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      random: 'lorem',
      letters:[],
      letter: ''
    }
  },
  splitLetter:function(){
   var s = this.state.random;
   for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    this.state.letters.push(s.charAt(i));
   }
   this.setState({
   letters:this.state.letters
   })
  },
  getLetter:function(e){
   var val = e.currentTarget.textContent;
   var _this = this;
    this.state.letters.forEach(function(letter) {
     if (letter === val) {
     alert("There is 'r' letter in the word.")
     console.log(letter, val);
     e.target.className = 'clicked';
     _this.setState({letter: letter})
    }
});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
      <p>The word is: <strong>{this.state.random}</strong></p>
      <p>Click the button first then click the r letter below</p>
        <button onClick={this.splitLetter}>Split letter</button>
        <p>Click on: <strong><span onClick={this.getLetter}>r</span></strong></p>
      {this.state.letters.map(function(item){  
  return (
       <div>
         <span className={item == this.state.letter ? 'foundedLetter' : ''}>{item}</span>  
      </div>
       )
    },this) /*added this to map function  */
    }
    </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyCom/>,
  document.getElementById("app")
)
```

for example: console.log(this.state.letters)

< span > H < /span >  --> this you can give className

H --> this you cant give className

Comment: I gave the letters class now!  '<span className={item}>{item}</span>' . Updated my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4vwarggo/1/ I just wanna give matched letter a class, so i can change its color.

Comment: I edited your code and i added the ref on your < span >, try out my fiddle i think it should work now. The problem is that you were trying to give className on a string instead of an element. you added a span but in the state you add still an array of strings. so you have to get the DOM element with the ref attribute and use the letters array as key for the reference.

Comment: Yea i know i am doing wrong , did this to show you.So where is your fiddle's link?

Comment: hmm.. okay i updated my comment above again. i created an extra state that keeps track of your current letter. if a state changes the render will map your letters again so i created a check on the span. this have to work! :)

Comment: The letter state is not changing.If it change, code should work.

Comment: sorry, this.setstate was in the foreeach so the this was the wrong "this" i update the fiddle now and it works :) i managed to see a red-coloured "r" :)

Comment: well yes :) , i created outside the foreach loop the variable _this and stored "this" in _this. with that i can use the this as _this in the foreach :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, when the letter to match is `'r'`, you want the r in `'lorem'` (spelled downwards with line-breaks between each letter) to have a special className. To do that you should selectively set a className in the render method using curly braces and JS-code:

```
{this.state.letters.map(function(item) {
    return (
        <div className={item === 'r' ? 'selected-letter' : ''}>
            {item}
        </div>
    )
})}
```

or the same thing using an arrow function.

```
{this.state.letters.map((item) =>
    <div className={item === 'r' ? 'selected-letter' : ''}>
        {item}
    </div>
)}
```

Here it is in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emd5x123/).

Of course, if you want to let the user select letter to match against, then it should be in the component state: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3wa9fn3/).

```
{this.state.letters.map((item) =>
    <div className={item === this.state.letterToMatch ? 'selected-letter' : ''}>
        {item}
    </div>
)}
```

### Edit

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gfztx4bz/) where you can select which letter to highlight as well.

```
onLetterSelected: function(e) {
    this.setState({
        letterToMatch: e.currentTarget.textContent
    });
}
```

Comment: In your 2 fiddles, 'r' has  .selected-letter class before clicking on it.

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't quite understand how you wanted it to work. So it's only supposed to highlight 'r' once you click on the 'r'??

Comment: Yea.When i click on 'r' and if it match, it gonna have the class.

Comment: Yah this works, thanks but what if i put more letter and make it array to check ? . How can i match them by putting them in array ? https://jsfiddle.net/4vwarggo/5/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Let's [continue in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128542/give-classname-to-the-matched-element-in-foreach-loop-with-react-js).